# Field error in object 'titulo' on field 'status': rejected value [Pendente];

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to learn Spring Framework on the go. During runtime I get following stacktrace:

> Validation failed for object='title'. Error count: 1
> org.springframework.validation.BindException:
> org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
> Field error in object 'title' on field 'status': rejected value
> [Received];

I noticed that the problem is in the status, which is formatted by enum, but I can't any error.

My class Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/titles")
public class registerTitleController {

@RequestMapping("/title") 
    public String new() {
        return "RegisterTitle"; 
    }

@Autowired 
    private Titles titles;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveIn(Title title) {
        titles.save(title);
        return "RegisterTitle";
    }
}
```

My class entity

```
@Entity
public class Title {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long cod;
    private String description;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateV;
    private BigDecimal val;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING) 
    private StatusTitle status;
   //other accessor methods
```

My class enum

```
public enum StatusTitle {
    PENDING("Pending"),
    RECEIVED("Received");   
    
    private String description;
    
    private StatusTitulo(String descricao){     
        this.description = description;
    }
    
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

My system work without the status of the attribute.

Can someone point out what is wrong? Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are sending `"Received"`, but you need to send `"RECEIVED"` string to properly convert to the `ENUM` by default.